# Masking passwords in Quarkus with default JBoss logger

Tags: passwords, httprequest, quarkus, masking, jboss-logging

In a Quarkus application i do some http calls where username and password are in the URL as query parameters (3rd party, I can't change this). The problem is, that the JBoss logger in DEBUG mode prints the call to the logfile and/or console with username and password as plain text.

Is there a way to filter or mask this output before the logger prints these information to the console or log file (or any other destination)?

As I found out, logback is not supported in Quarkus (at the moment).

The main point is, that Quarkus prints in debug-log-mode everything from the http call in plaintext to the log out. I think I need to grab the log output at very low level to filter it.

Comment: You should be able to use some kind of `java.util.logging.Filter` to handle this.

Comment: Do you have an example how this is done? It is very hard to find working examples for Quarkus.

Comment: I'm not a Quarkus expert, but maybe this is helpful https://quarkus.io/guides/logging.